# Golang Comments seem to alter the compiler input (Sliver)

Tags: go, github, compilation

I found a in interesting project on Github mainly written in Golang containing comments which seem to change the way the code is compiled:
https://github.com/BishopFox/sliver/blob/master/implant/sliver/sliver.go#L37

```golang
// {{if .Config.IsBeacon}}
"sync"
// {{end}}
```

How is this method of altering the compilation called and how can it be defined - is this default go?

Comment: That looks like a go template. The go file might be something that is processed before building the actual program.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @burak-serdar , this is most likely due to the usage of the `template` package - as seen here: https://github.com/BishopFox/sliver/blob/978a66bdb0c93adec7cd81721428ca89340830ec/server/generate/binaries.go#L599